# Can Socket.io listen on multiple ports?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Is it possible for socket.io to listen on multiple ports in one server?

**Background** - I need to satisfy two problems:

1.Some cooperate & other closed networks block all traffic which does not use port 80.

2.Some anti viruses block websocket traffic on port 80. Port 4000 is the safest port to use.

I therefore need to my node server to be able to use port 80 and 4000 simultaneously. Has anyone experienced similar problems? How did you solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: I assume if websockets are blocked on port 80, socket.io will try other transports...

Comment: @Alfred - that is right. It drops down to xhr or jsonp-polling. But even then, the connection is intermittent and not reliable. The anti virus software also affects these transports.

Comment: how about flash transport... P.S: I don't have any experience with this, but I guess this is interesting question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your process is listening on port 4000, it's my understanding you can use iptables to internally forward requests for port 80.

```
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 4000
```

/edit got the ports the wrong way around.